# Will extending an already extended facebook token at some point re-extend?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token, facebook-authentication

I've read [the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension) and poked around quite a bit online but can't seem to find a sure answer for this. My app [TinyShow](http://www.tinyshow.com/) sucks in Facebook events from users and pages. The initial token refresh works great for both users and pages - I get the promised 60 day extension.

However, my app is similar to [Buffer](https://buffer.com/app) in that I want users to set it and forget it. There's no reason for an event contributor to log back in (well not yet, at least). When I re-extend the facebook access token I get one back with an expiration time of 60 days minus the time of the first extension. So if a user signs up 2 days ago at which point I extend the token, I get a 58 day expiration time if I extend it today. This is true for both user access tokens and page access tokens. Let's say I have a cron job that extends the token once per day. Will Facebook at some point extend the token another 60 days?

On a related note, in the Extending Page Access Tokens section of [the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension) I see "The resulting page access token will not have any expiry time." However, extending the page access token does in fact return an expiry time. The payload looks like this:

```
{
    "access_token" => "secret",
         "expires" => "5022613"
}
```

I find it hard to believe the docs are wrong (although it's possible). Am I misunderstanding that statement?

Comment: You can not extend user access tokens without user interaction. (If that was possible, then removing offline_access permission would not have made much sense in the first place.) // A page access token that got via an extended user token should not have any default expiry; most likely you did something wrong in the process.

Comment: @CBroe I figured out the reason I am getting an expiry time. It's because I am extending the page access token when that is unnecessary if the user token is already extended. However, this makes me think when Facebook says "The resulting page access token will not have any expiry time." it does not mean they will never expire, it just means it will expire when the user's token expires. Do you know if page tokens will expire when the user token expires?

Comment: When you extend a user token that includes manage_pages permission, the user token automatically becomes "unlimited" as well. That's due to Facebook's internal implementation of non-expiring page tokens - those still have to be tied to a specific user, because the user might be removed as page admin, and then their page access token has to become invalid, too. If the user changes their account password, that will invalidate the page token as well. But other than that, it doesn't expire, as long as it was requested using an already extended user token.